# Database after restore process still display Restoring

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

I restored `Database` from `Backup File` (in `Management Studio`) and after restore, Database showed `Restoring`, then I deleted files from disk (engine's stopped), then I tried Restore again with success, on both cases I leave Restore Process on `Default Options`

I have no idea why, dump file I created after restart of enviroment, without active `Connection`(s)

my question: is possible somehow to stop the `Restoring` status, if is there some tools for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, a DB is not ready to use. It stays "restoring" ready to receive log restores.

Simply run this to bring the DB on-line

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB WITH RECOVERY
```

Or using the GUI, this is step 12 in the [MSDN SSMS "how to"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx) (a different place to what you mention)

Comment: +1 thanks for basic stuff, but I'm curious that on second attempt same dump, same virtual, same DbName and Databases was restored and works, hmmm btw that I never seen by using Sql_2005

Comment: @mKorbel: It could be some setting in the GUI, for example whether the DB exists or not. I almost always use raw SQL so can't really say sorry.

Answer (score -2):

So there are three ways you can restore the database

1. No recovery RESTORE DATABASE MyDB WITH NORECOVERY
2. Recovery RESTORE DATABASE MyDB WITH RECOVERY
3. Standby RESTORE DATABASE MyDB WITH Standby

Thanks,
Piyush Patel